# Is there an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with setwise coprime coefficients that is composite for all integer arguments?

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

There are lots of questions here and on the web about polynomials that produce prime values. I'm asking the opposite: is there a nontrivial polynomial $p(n)$ that *never* produces primes?

Specifically, the polynomial must:

1. be irreducible over the integers
2. have coefficients that as a set have a greatest common divisor of 1
3. evaluate to a composite number for all integer arguments.

I suspect that such a polynomial does not exist. I've tried using the set of prime factors of $p(0)$ (the constant term) and $p(1)$ (the sum of coefficients) to generate an argument $m$ such that $p(m)$ is relatively prime to each of $p(0)$ and $p(1)$, but I can't really get anywhere with that approach. I don't have any other ideas of what to try.

Comment: Edit:$x^2+x+2$ does not work (is prime precisely for x=0,-1). 

If you modify your gcd condition to a stronger condition (that all *terms* of the sequence are coprime), then your conjecture is believed to be true and is related to an open problem: Bunyakovsky’s conjecture.

Comment: @TejasRao - Except $x^2 + x + 2\mid_0 = 2$ is prime.

Comment: $x^2+x+4$ should work. It is always even and always greater than 2

Comment: How about $p(x) = 2$?

Comment: @TejasRao - Yes, that works. Now I feel silly for not finding something simple like that myself. :(

Comment: @TedHopp It is very counterintuitive at first glance. Like I said above if you just strengthen your gcd condition a tad your conjecture is likely true. Further there are believed to be infinitely many primes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ can be primitive, yet some $d>1$ divides all of the numbers $P(n)$. No surprise, the polynomial $\frac{P(x)}{d}$ must have all values at natural numbers integral. Such polynomials are characterized as linear combinations of $\frac{x(x-1)\cdots (x-k+1)}{k!}$ with integral coefficients. Now multiplying by some integers, we can ensure that the polynomial is in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, primitive, yet the numbers $P(n)$ have a common divisor.